# Cant get codeigniter hooks working

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I have spent several hours now, trying to figure out why i can't get a simple hook working in codeigniter.

I have enabled hooks in config.
i tripplechecked spelling and case.

I wrote the code below in config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
'class'    => '',
'function' => 'set_previous_page',
'filename' => 'previous_page',
'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

And then my previous_page.php file which is located in hooks folder:

```
function set_previous_page()
{
    echo "Hi!"; die;
}
```

Obviously the purpose is not to echo Hi! and then stop the script execution, but it's just to get it working. And i did try several hook points. But pre_controller i should be able to output hi and kill the script, and then have hi as the only output.

But when i load my pages, it just loads as normal.

I tried on purpose, to mess up the syntax in the hook array, and it did give me an error, and the rest of the page was not loaded. That just tells me that, at least it does recognize that i have turned hooks on.

But from here on i am just lost. Dont know what to do?

Do you have any ideas? I'll try and sleep on it now, and hope that some smart fella in here has the answer! Thankyou in advance!

**EDIT:** By the way, i am using MX (modular extensions), phil sturgeons template library and Ion auth. Dont really think they should have an impact.

Comment: Have you tried adding the function inside class as in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html? It says class is optional but it is better if you try that also. I used with class without any issue.

Comment: Just tried it, and it made no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look like the code in the manual. Did you check it?

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

I just tried it locally, and it works fine.

application/config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
   'class' => '',
   'function' => 'Myfunction',
   'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
   'filepath' => 'hooks',
   'params' => ''
);
```

application/hooks/Myclass.php:

```
<?php

function Myfunction(){

    echo "wut wut";
    die;
}
```

With this all set, I visit the page and get a `wut wut`.

You're missing the `php` extension in the filename, but that'd throw an `unexpected end of input` exception if everything else was working.

Comment: I actually found out earlier, i had just gotten so used to, not writing the extension when dealing with roues and so on in codeigniter. But that was the solution (: thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This maybe very late respond, just incase someone encounter this kind of issue same as me using CI 3.x. Just make sure you enable hooks in config/config.php file `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;` before you put entry in the config/hooks.php